# Inline CSS Does Not Work When Transferred to External Stylesheet

Tags: css

I don't get why the background image disappears when I transfer the inline CSS to external stylesheet. Here's the CSS:

```
.col {
     margin-top:-20px;
     width: 20%;
     float: left;
     }
.col li {
     font-size:9px;
     padding:10px 10px 10px 0px;
     border-bottom:1px solid #f6f4e7;
     line-height:15px;
     }
.col li:hover {
     background:#f7f3e3;
     }

.sample span {
     background:url(../image.jpg) no-repeat left;
     padding: 10px 0;
     padding-left:35px;
     }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="col">
<li class="sample"><span><a href="/webpage">anchor text</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS for `col` and `col.li` work fine when transferred to the external stylesheet. But as soon as I transfer the css for `.sample span`, that's when the image background disappears. Also, as far as I know, the class names are unique and I don't see a case of overriding.

Any idea why this is?

Comment: The image path is relative; first to the HTML document where you had it declared inline, and then to the stylesheet. Make the image path relative to the stylesheet.

Answer (score 4):

`url(...)` is relative to the file it is found in. So when it is in the html file, it tries to load `../image.jpg` from the HTML file location. When you move it to the CSS file, if the css file is in a different folder, it may search a different folder.

Make the url either absolute or adjust it to be relative to the .css file and your code should work.

A way you can confirm this in the future btw is to hit F12 in the browser, then click the element and check the css rules. It has debugging info that includes the active rules and links to images to inspect.